# change position landscape or portrait in react

Tags: reactjs, landscape-portrait

i have a landscape and portrait image. how can i pop up it correctly ?

my pop up:

```
 <Modal
      visible={this.state.visible}
      width="600"
      height="400"
      effect="fadeInUp"
      onClickAway={() => this.closeModal()}
    >
      <div>
        <img
          src={"/img/" + this.state.LinkName}
          width="600"
          height="400"
          alt="Houston We have pb"
        />
```

my idea, i will add "land" and "portrait" string to each image.
so i can test `this.state.LinkName.contains("Land")` then

```
width = 600 and height = 400 


else width = 400 and height = 600
```

how can i do that in react ?

i am newbie in react technologie.

i modifie the code :

```
 handleButtonClick = (e, row) => { 
    var bild = new Image();
    bild.src = "/img/" + row.original.Cert;
    //Image.getSize(bild.src, (width, height) => {this.setState({width, height})}); 
    //const {width, height} = Image.resolveAssetSource(bild.src);
    var Pos
    bild.onload = function()
    {
      Pos = bild.width > bild.height ? "Land" : "Port";        
    }  
    this.setState({ visible: true, LinkName: row.original.Cert, ThePos: Pos });   
  };
```

Now i get the real width and height.

the problem now, the variable ThePos is always undifined.

Comment: first get image height and width
then store into state, and update modal and image height and width using same property
after all set vissible true

Comment: have you height and width for each image?

Comment: handleButtonClick = (e, row) => { 
    var bild = new Image();
    bild.src = "/img/" + row.original.Cert;
    //Image.getSize(bild.src, (width, height) => {this.setState({width, height})}); 
    //const {width, height} = Image.resolveAssetSource(bild.src);
    var Pos = bild.width > bild.height ? "Land" : "Port";
    this.setState({ visible: true, LinkName: row.original.Cert, ThePos: Pos, TheSource:bild.src.height });
  }; the problem is bild.width and height always 0

Comment: if height and width always zero then how will you decide Modal will be **( land || Port )**

Comment: because of that...that is the problem

Comment: then first get height and width correctly
without height and width , you cant do nothing

Comment: can you tell me how can i get height and widht correctly

Comment: check this link
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/626505/6422021

Answer (score 1):

You can just test on `this.state.LinkName.contains("Land")`

like this:

```
 render(){
      return(
     <Modal
          visible={this.state.visible}
          width={this.state.LinkName.contains("Land")? "600" : "400"}
          height={this.state.LinkName.contains("Land")? "400" : "600"}
          effect="fadeInUp"
          onClickAway={() => this.closeModal()}
        >
          <div>
            <img
              src={"/img/" + this.state.LinkName}
              width={this.state.LinkName.contains("Land")? "600" : "400"}
              height={this.state.LinkName.contains("Land")? "400" : "600"}
              alt="Houston We have pb"
            />
     </Modal>
    )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i found it:

```
  handleButtonClick = (e, row) => { 
var bild = new Image();
bild.src = "/img/" + row.original.Cert;   
bild.onload = () =>   
this.setState({ visible: true, LinkName: row.original.Cert, ThePos: bild.width > bild.height ? "Land" : "Port" });
```

};